# Problems uninstalling a program using Ubuntu Software

Tags: software-installation, uninstall

I'm new to Ubuntu and would like to uninstall the software 0 A.D. (which I saw in the store).  I uninstalled it through Ubuntu Software, but it is still in my applications menu.

I have also tried uninstalling the software using the terminal, but I'm not sure of the name of the package. I was unsuccessful with trying `0 A.D.` and `pyrogenesis` as that's what the app is called in the side menu.

Comment: The best method of uninstall is to reverse how it was installed. You haven't mentioned your release of Ubuntu, but Gnome Software can install snaps & debs, and multiple versions can be found (eg. a snap version, a deb version..) so it's easy to think they are same but if you installed one version and try to remove the other, nothing will happen on removal.  Myself I like package managers (`muon`, `synaptic` etc) will deal only with a single type of package (debs in that case) so I'm less confused.  General comment only

Comment: In your case I'd `snap list` to view snaps installed; if it was found, `snap remove <name>` Next look for deb packages with something like `dpkg -l |grep 0ad` then if found `sudo apt remove <name>`  (where <name> is like `0ad` as I'd expect the -data & -data-common to be removed later automatically..)  If you want a GUI way, you'll have to wait for others..

Answer (score 0):

Found the official package name at https://play0ad.com/download/linux/#Ubuntuprovidedpackages

so please run `sudo apt uninstall 0ad && sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:wfg/0ad` to remove the game and its [PPA](https://itsfoss.com/ppa-guide/).